# File Upload in each row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a File upload control inside a gridview item template like

```
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:FileUpload ID="flUpload"  runat="server" />
     </ItemTemplate>
```

And i have a button outside the grid view which says upload and i want to upload all files in the grid view one by one. But my problem is that when i select some file in the file upload control the upload button is not firing the click event. Let me know if there is some way the click will work.

Comment: Are your other events like `Load` being fired?

Comment: no, nothing fires. it functions like if i click upload it clears the 1st row data in the file uploader and then 2nd on 2nd click and if every data from file uploader is removed then it fires load or click event.

Comment: Is this grid inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no, its just simple gridview inside an html table

Comment: Then I have no clue what could be causing the weird behavior. I have used FileUpload in a grid without any issue. It uploads all the files together. Lets hope someone else can help you on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are three templates in a gridview per column. You have placed the FU in the static or display 'item' template. Move it to the edit or the other one(not at a computer to see the name). If your grid is inside a 'update Panel' the FU control is not compatable with it either.

You also should consider creating a detailsview and place it in there so when the user selects that row they can edit upload whatever you need. Forget my updat panel thing I see you already answered that.

Comment: i dont have any edit template in my gridview.. i am doing everything in item template and i want to keep it that way. user can see the control as soon as he sees the page.

Comment: You can change the mode in the gridview to start in editmode so that they don't have to click anything. By making all your colums template columns you can show or add what you want.  Change all your columns to edittemplates but leave your contents he same. The item template is like a PDF file not really made to be edited. Thats why you should use the edit template.